# Как правильно читать синтаксис C++

Tags: c++, syntax

Всем здравствуйте! Проходил я как то тест по C++ и наткнулся на такую строчку:

```
Array <cClass> &v = m_value;
```

Сам понимаю что тут мы имеем дело с типом данных cClass, который передаётся в шаблон класса Array, берём адрес объекта класса (v) и присваиваем туда значение из переменной m_value.

Вопрос такой: как правильно прочитать эту строку или я уже описал правильно выше?

Comment: Ну это обычная ссылка на объект класса `Array<cClass>`. Вот вам пример посложнее: `using wat = char ( & ( cClass::* [1] ) (cClass( * )[2]) & )[3];`

Comment: Ммммм, переносим wat в глобальную область видимости, а потом инициализируем её массивом char из 4-х элементов (во 2 и 3 элементы пишем указатели на класс cClass)?

Comment: очень холодно...

Comment: Видимо не до конца разобрался, можете просветить?))

Comment: Там объявляется алиас `wat` для массива из одного указателя на нестатическую функцию-член класса `cClass`, имеющую lvalue reference квалификатор, принимающую указатель на массив из двух объектов `cClass` и возвращающую ссылку на массив из 3 `char`. Читается, как и другие объявления, по спиральному правилу.

Comment: ок, спасибо почитаю статейку на эту тему дополнительно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> берём адрес объекта класса (v)

Нет, это не так. Это объявление ссылки `v` на объект типа `Array <cClass>`. В данном случае ссылка инициализируется объектом `m_value`, т.е. `v` - ссылка на `m_value`.

Comment: Ну получается можно сказать что Array - это шаблон класса, а cClass тип, передаваемый в шаблон?

Comment: @WideWood Обычно говорят, что `cClass` - это "аргумент" шаблона, но вообще да.

Comment: Ок спасибо за пояснение)